# Manually triggering HTML 5 datepicker

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am making a PhoneGap app primarily aimed at the Android platform and I have been replacing some default behavior for various form elements because I'm using touch events and I have managed to reinitialize some default behavior like so:

```
function addSlideToRemove(element) {
    element.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0];
        window.touchStartX = parseInt(touchobj.clientX);
        hoveredElement = document.elementFromPoint(touchobj.clientX, touchobj.clientY);

        function toggleCheckbox(element) {
            if (element.checked == true) {
                element.checked = false;
            } else {
                element.checked = true;
            }
        }

        switch (hoveredElement.tagName) {

        case 'INPUT':
            if (hoveredElement.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
                toggleCheckbox(hoveredElement);
            } else {
                hoveredElement.focus();
            }
            break;

        case 'LABEL':
            labelFor = hoveredElement.getAttribute('for');
            toggleCheckbox(document.getElementById(labelFor));
            break;

        }
    }, false);
}
```

So, now I've got the fields to get focus when they or their corresponding labels are touched, but I am facing a problem with the date fields. They get focus, but I don't know a method to toggle the date polyfill for a `<input type="date" />` using JavaScript.

I don't want to rely on 3rd party JavaScript libraries or plugins for a single date picker, as the native android one is the one I'm planning to use and I'm trying to keep as much of the Android user experience.

Comment: have you tried bootstrap datepicker its easy. If you want the code I can provide which you can use.

Comment: Well... I'm using Bootstrap already for the CSS, but I was only planning to use jQuery as a last resort. And this looks like the last resort.